Typeorm Subscibrers UpdateEvent
async afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<Experience>) {
    const old_pub = event.databaseEntity;
    const new_pub = event.entity as Experience;

    const statusJustChanged = old_pub.status != new_pub.status;
    if (statusJustChanged) {
        // ... MAKE SOME UPDATES
    }
}

The Typeorm Subscribers system don't really work the way i expected.
Some problems with my code above are:

Sometimes the event.databaseEntity is null (eg: when the update is done without loading the enity first, i.e via the Repository.update method for eg)
The event.entity is of type ObjectLiteral. Sometimes it only holds a list of the specific updated columns.

So just to be short, my question is how can be sure to check old_pub.status != new_pub.status afert every updates without my code crashing.
